# How to search my own created list C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

I was wondering if it's possible to search a list I created such as:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    string trans, descr;
    List<ErrorInfo> errList = new List<ErrorInfo>();

    if (errList.Find(trans) && errList.Find(desc)) {
        // do something
    }
}

public class ErrorInfo {
    public string transaction { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

I know that the if condition is incorrect but what I want to do is search through the list and see if any node contains trans && descr, but I don't understand how to do that or if it's possible?

Comment: if only we had some sort of  _Language Integrated Query_ feature...

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
if (errList.Any(e => e.transaction == trans && e.description == descr))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Gotta love the drive-by downvote with absolutely no explanation of where it falls short. Useless.

Comment: I wasn't aware of LINQ but it's working as I intended. Thanks for the help!